# Laravel Application start events

Tags: php, asp.net-mvc-4, laravel-5

Coming from an ASP.NET MVC background I'm building my first PHP app and have been using the Laravel framework. I'm used to having application start events. This provides a convenient method to do things like populate cache objects and set timers to ensure these cache object refresh with my storage regularly prior to the app serving any requests.

This means that lists of stuff are already there rather than being retrieved from the server on every request. I can't find any similar application start hooks for Laravel or indeed PHP off which Laravel is based.

I can of course just Lazy load cache objects on demand. This means one or two requests will suffer increased latency as they will result in trips to the database server. Not unacceptable but wondered what the PHP/Laravel solution to this problem is.

Thanks,

Comment: [Service Providers](https://laravel.com/docs/master/providers)

Comment: That, or [Middleware](https://laravel.com/docs/master/middleware). Service Providers are probably what you are looking for. Middleware is for filtering/handling the request itself (authentication, managing headers, etc).

Comment: Not sure it's middleware as this seems to allow me to add processing before and after requests as some form of decorator pattern. Handy stuff. Service providers is looking more promising. Any more pointers on where the events for this are described?

Comment: I suggest understanding the [lifecycle](https://laravel.com/docs/master/lifecycle) in general. Otherwise, I've provided you several links to the Laravel documentation. You should really read through and understand the docs.